# Index is working on one Column but not working on another column same table iN mysql PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql

Currently, I have uploaded about 500 million records on PHPMyAdmin MySQL. For fast searching I used index. There is two columns from which I want to do searching and for that, I had created an index on both. After indexing one column becomes too fast and another column searching is the same as before indexing. I have about 30 40 tables and I did indexing on all and MySQL shows that indexing is successful but when I am doing searching it is slow. I am not able to figure out what is wrong with that.

This is the image. I have added index on n and cnic column. Working fine in n but not on cnic.

select statement is following

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE n='$VARIABLE' // WORKINGG VVERY FAST
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE cnic='$VARIABLE' //working slow
```

[image: phpmyadmin table]

Comment: Please provide sample table table data and the select statement that's not fast enough. Also try "explain extended" before the query to see if the index you created is being used.

Comment: Probably you need to create separate indexes for 2 columns

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I have added separate index for both column.

Comment: @AaronJ I have added tbl image with query

Comment: Dunno. Looks fine to me. Does it show it's using the index when you do `explain extended SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE cnic='$VARIABLE'` ?  Maybe try dropping and recreating the index I guess.

Comment: @AaronJ I try your query and it gives me some results. But dunno how to check its using index or not. Can you guide me on how to check?

Comment: @AaronJ it is showing m,e that it is using index

Comment: If the query uses the index and it is still slow, then you can still look at the number of records that the slow query returns. It is possible it returns a large resultset, which takes time to assemble and transfer over to the php code. I t is also possible that you have exhausted the programming possibilities to speed up your query and you need to turn to DBA tools, such as adjusting mysql server settings. There already are dozens of answers here on SO and the DBA sister site of SO regarding optimal mysql configuration.

Comment: @Shadow Data is about too much but after index one column becomes too fast but on the same side, another same table column is too slow with the same type of data search and query. It takes about 1-3min to search.

Comment: "I had created an index on both." -- Do you mean a single index on both columns? (bad for your question)  Or two single-column indexes? (good, for your question)  Be specific by providing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @DarkCoder We can not tell what your datatypes are until you post TEXT RESULTS of  SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;  Also, we can not tell what your datatype is for the variable you are using.

Comment: @WilsonHauck My all columns datatypes are VarChar

Comment: @RickJames My all columns datatypes are VarChar and I had put an index on one by one both varchar columns 'collumn n' and 'column cnic'

Comment: @DarkCoder No one can really help you if you will not provide A) EXPLAIN SELECT ....; B) prep to get your variables ready and C) SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name; and you could get other requests for information.

Comment: @DarkCoder - How many rows have the value you selected for via `cnic`?  What is the collation of that column?  What is `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`?